# DevExpress CustomRowFilter - how to trigger?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I'm very new to C# programming, so am hoping this is something simple that I'm overlooking.

I have a XtraGrid.GridControl on my form which I want to apply a CustomRowFilter against.

I am not explicitly defining any views for the grid, so I thought I'd be adding my CustomRowFilter method to an event handler against the MainView on my GridControl - however I can't find how to access the event I'm after?

Is this the right approach or am going about this the wrong way?

```
    private void gridControl1_CustomRowFilter(object sender, RowFilterEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView view = sender as GridView;
        DataView dv = view.DataSource as DataView;

        if (1==1) //Temp - this should hide everything
        {
            e.Visible = false;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Bind the datasource etc...

        gridControl1.MainView.CustomRowFilter += gridControl1_CustomRowFilter //"Base view does not contain a definition for "CustomRowFilter"
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CustomRowFilter` event belongs to the `GridView` and not to `GridControl`, You can access the event with :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    (gridControl1.MainView as GridView).CustomRowFilter += gridControl1_CustomRowFilter;
}
```